# Binary Tree delete function error

Tags: c++

Hey I want to delete a node from my binary tree. I know a node cannot be deleted if it has both right and left children. So I have written code accordingly. But every time the program runs, it crashes.

```
void btdel(btree *b, char d)
{
    if (b->lchild->data!=d&&b->lchild!=NULL)
    btdel(b->lchild,d);
    if (b->rchild->data!=d&&b->rchild!=NULL)
    btdel(b->rchild,d);
    if (b->lchild!=NULL&&b->lchild->data==d)
    {
        if (b->lchild->rchild==NULL)
           b->lchild=b->lchild->lchild;
        else if (b->lchild->lchild==NULL)
           b->lchild=b->lchild->rchild;
           else {cout<<"cannot delete"; exit(1);
           }
    }
    else if (b->rchild!=NULL&&b->rchild->data==d)
    {
        if (b->rchild->rchild==NULL)
           b->rchild=b->rchild->lchild;
        else if (b->rchild->lchild==NULL)
           b->rchild=b->rchild->rchild;
        else
        {cout<<"Cannot delete. "; exit(1);}
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does it crash?

Comment: Might as well check that b != NULL too.

Answer (score 2):

Quick look:

```
if (b->lchild->data!=d && b->lchild!=NULL)
```

should be:

```
if (b->lchild!=NULL && b->lchild->data!=d)
```

you need to check `b->lchild` if it has a valid address before reading its data.

Comment: Same issue a couple of lines down btw for `b->rchild`.